# Loading jreviews fields from database

Tags: php, database, joomla, pull

In my example I will show in other module the prices of each article. 
I use this code (hv try several codes) but it only shows **one price** on all listings. I think it's first in sql ..

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select ($db->quoteName('jr_price'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__jreviews_content'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select ($db->quoteName('jr_price'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__jreviews_content'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$prices = $db->loadColumn();

foreach ($prices as $price) {
    echo $price.'<br />;
}
?>
```

Comment: how to use ihv jr_pris and not price

Answer (score 1):

`loadResult()` only loads a single result. I would suggest you use `loadObjectList` or `loadColumn` and then use a `foreach` loop to display your results.

The following documentation page will ve very helpful for you:

https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: can you be more specific please how to use `foreach` and 'loadColumn' maybe example in mine code thx for answer

Comment: i hv used this code but it shows now in all articles all prices from db: 
`<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select ($db->quoteName('jr_pris'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__jreviews_content'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$column= $db->loadColumn();
print_r($column);


?>`

Comment: it shows all results from sql with code foreach loadcolumn

Answer (score 0):

i found solution to add to code above

```
$result = $db->loadResult();
print_r($result);
```